# Debian stretch rsync is never ending

Tags: rsync

Situation. Backup-hd over USB2 (yes, it is little bit slow)

Udev-Rules to mount partion for /home-backup (only 1 user) in /media/partition-label.

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/debianhome type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
```

` The  udev-rule triggers a systemd-unit created by me.

```
   cat /etc/systemd/system/backup-home-skript.service 
[Unit]
Description=backup-home-skript 
RequiresMountsFor=/media/debianhome
After=media-debianhome.mount

[Service]
Type=simple
User=alex
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/backup-home-skript
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=15s
```

So, far so good.

```
systemctl status backup-home-skript.service 
● backup-home-skript.service - backup-home-skript
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/backup-home-skript.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-11-08 16:04:41 CET; 4h 26min ago
 Main PID: 23143 (backup-home-skr)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/backup-home-skript.service
           ├─23143 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/backup-home-skript
           ├─23191 rsync -aAXEovvchx --ignore-existing --verbose --exclude=/home/alex/iso-image/ --exclude=/home/alex/.cache/ --excl
           ├─23192 rsync -aAXEovvchx --ignore-existing --verbose --exclude=/home/alex/iso-image/ --exclude=/home/alex/.cache/ --excl
           └─23404 rsync -aAXEovvchx --ignore-existing --verbose --exclude=/home/alex/iso-image/ --exclude=/home/alex/.cache/ --excl

Nov 08 16:04:41 Taomon systemd[1]: Started backup-home-skript.
```

Backup-home-skript

```
cat /usr/local/bin/backup-home-skript
#!/bin/bash

echo "wating for device to become ready" >> /home/alex/rsync.log


/bin/sleep 45

while ! \
  rsync -aAXEovvchx --ignore-existing --verbose \
       --exclude=/home/alex/iso-image/  \
       --exclude=/home/alex/.cache/ \
       --exclude=/home/alex/.thumbnails/ \
       --exclude=/home/alex/rsync.log \
       /home/alex/ /media/debianhome/alex >> /home/alex/rsync.log
do
  sleep 60
  echo "retrying" >> /home/alex/rsync.log
done

/usr/bin/aplay -q /home/alex/Musik/Wave/game-over.wav
echo "rsync done" >> /home/alex/rsync.log

exit 0
```

For 2h rsync stuck here

```
tail -n10 rsync.log 
send_files mapped /home/alex/.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35CBBC56B8E501F758A3BED2CD20C52E5694F9E5 of size 53947
calling match_sums /home/alex/.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35CBBC56B8E501F758A3BED2CD20C52E5694F9E5
.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35CBBC56B8E501F758A3BED2CD20C52E5694F9E5
sending file_sum
false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
sender finished /home/alex/.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35CBBC56B8E501F758A3BED2CD20C52E5694F9E5
send_files(13899, /home/alex/.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35ED5D22AB261A928FEA2B5079701D5DF254CF71)
send_files mapped /home/alex/.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35ED5D22AB261A928FEA2B5079701D5DF254CF71 of size 17369
calling match_sums /home/alex/.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35ED5D22AB261A928FEA2B5079701D5DF254CF71
.cache/mozilla/firefox/tv7fce7g.default/cache2/entries/35ED5D22AB261A928FEA2B5079701D5DF254CF71
```

I don't understand what rsync is doing. Do not --exclude mean let this in peace?
Sometimes it works, sometimes not. [dmesg   filtrated](https://pastebin.ca/3906626)

Is something wrong with /usr/local/bin/backup-home-skript or my systemd-unit? I hope I gave all relevant infos.

New attempt.

```
rsync -aAXEovvvchxs --ignore-existing  \
       --exclude={iso-image,*cache*,*thumb*,rsync.log*,.*}
```

Now it stucks by an image.

```
mediainfo enna/enna-0.4.0/data/theme/default/images/unknown_cover.png 
General
Complete name                            : enna/enna-0.4.0/data/theme/default/images/unknown_cover.png
Format                                   : PNG
Format/Info                              : Portable Network Graphic
File size                                : 217 KiB

Image
Format                                   : PNG
Format/Info                              : Portable Network Graphic
Width                                    : 600 pixels
Height                                   : 600 pixels
Bit depth                                : 32 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Stream size                              : 217 KiB (100%)
```

Time for smartmontools.

Comment: Might add in if any of the 'rsync' processes have files open (`lsof`) or what directory they are in (`/proc/$PID/cwd`).  Is it changing, or is it stuck on a particular file?

Comment: rsync --exclude patterns starting with `/` are relative to the source path ("root of the transfer"). See manpage section _INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES_ for more details.

Comment: Yes thanks for your special instructions. I didn't know when I ask my question, that the Harddrive is broken.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, it turned out as an hardware failure.

```
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always   Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       10%      1145         1887144880    -       168
`
```